# The code Socket clientSocket = new Socket(); crashes in android app even in separate thread

Tags: java, android, sockets, crash

I am new to Android and I've been working on this bug for a while but still didn't figure it out. I am trying to send a message to a server running on my laptop from my smartphone. The issue is that for some reason it crashes when creating a socket (not immediately but after a couple of seconds). Even though I have the permissions (.INTERNET) and run the code in a separate thread it still fails.

```
public class Communcation extends Activity{
private Socket s = null;
short REDIRECTED_SERVERPORT = 5000;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_communcation);

    final EditText msg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMsg);
    Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSend);
    final TextView convo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvConvo);
    convo.setText("");
    final TextView status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);
    status.setText("");
    Button connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConnect);
    final EditText ipaddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);

    connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            status.setText("Estabilishing the connection to " + ipaddress.getText().toString());
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        s = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(ipaddress.getText().toString()), REDIRECTED_SERVERPORT);
                        status.setText("Established connection..");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        status.setText("Failed the connection" + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });

    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String message = msg.getText().toString();
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    PrintWriter outp = null;
                    BufferedReader inp = null;
                    String serverMsg = null;

                    try {
                        outp = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
                        inp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        status.setText("Couldn't initate the buffers ");
                    }

                    outp.write(message);
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });
}
```

}

On my server side code I wait for a connection and print a message but from testing the code so far it never passes the accept part.

```
    while (1)
{   int clientfd;
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    int addrlen=sizeof(client_addr);

    /*---accept a connection (creating a data pipe)---*/
    printf("[SERVER] Waiting for clients\n");
    clientfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &addrlen);
    printf("%s:%d connected\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));

    recv(clientfd, buffer, MAXBUF, 0);
    printf("[SERVER] Received from the client: [%s]\n", buffer);

    /*---Close data connection---*/
    close(clientfd);
}
```

Comment: Post your stack trace.

Comment: 'The code crashes' is not a problem description.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I can tell in this case without it.  You set the text of the text view on the same thread.  You can only touch Views in the UI thread.  You need to either post a Runnable to a Handler, or use runOnUiThread on the UI code.